# How to use distinct keyword in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, subquery, having-clause

I tried the following query :

```
select class
from courses
WHERE distinct student
having count(class)>=5 ;
```

Basically I am trying to get all the classes that have count more than 5.On the same time 
I am trying not to have duplicate students. So it means a student can correspond just to one class. But I am having a syntax error. Any help would be appreciated.
Example input:
{"headers": {"courses": ["student", "class"]}, "rows": {"courses": [["A", "Math"], ["B", "English"], ["C", "Math"], ["D", "Biology"], ["E", "Math"], ["F", "Math"], ["A", "Math"]]}}
Example output:
{"headers":["class"],"values":[]}

Comment: I'm not clear on the objective.  How do students fit into your schema?

Comment: So lets say the  tables is in this format: 
(Student A,Math)
(Student B,Math)
(Student A,Math)
I dont want Student A to count twice.

Comment: If a student belongs to several classes, in which class do you want to count him in?

Comment: It counts just once!

Comment: Apparently the right answer is :
```
select class
FROM
    courses
GROUP BY class
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT student) >= 5
;

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want classes with five or more students, you want aggregation:

```
select class
from courses
group by class
having count(*) >= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want classes that have at least 5 students that do not belong to another class.

If so, you can use aggregation and `not exists`:

```
select class
from courses c
where not exists (
    select 1 from class c1 where c1.class <> c.class and c1.student = c.student
)
group by class
having count(*) > 5
```